# Angular 5 not able to create simple project

Tags: angular5

I am new to angular, and starting with angular 5.
I have just installed node-v8.11.3-x64, 
and run below commands :

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
ng -v & npm -v
```

[image]

and finally run below command :

```
ng new "hello-hello"
```

but getting below error

[image]

please help me to get rid of it.

[For @fabi_K](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3K6A.png)

[For @fabi_k after cleaning cache](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRlm9.png)

Comment: Could you include the log from the path shown in the image.

Comment: @Akshay I am trying to attach log file, but its too large.
can you pleas help me how can i attach the log file as an attachment ?

Comment: Looks like your package.json is likely not formatted correctly. Did you make manual changes?

Comment: @IanMacDonald, No I have done only steps described above.

Comment: Okay, this seems like tricky npm issue. As I see this, one of the package.json files of your dependencies is broken. I would try to clean the cache as well as the node modules in your project folder and the install the dependencies again

Comment: npm cache clean —force

Comment: @fabi_k now clean the cache as per given command, but now getting some more error. attached screen shot.

Comment: Okay, next try:

Comment: Set strict-ssl in your npm config to false: npm config strict-ssl false

Comment: And then try it again with npm install

Comment: @fabi_k it just worked now !

Thank you so much :)

can you please share me knowledge what causes it to get impacted, and what happens if we make strict-ssl false ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have an issue by installing your dependencies. Just skip that part and run `npm install -d` und your generated project.

When you are behind a corporate proxy, ensure that your npm proxy settings are set correctly.

Comment: What the CLI does is generating code as well as adding dependencies to your package.json. Afterwards it tries a npm install, but this step fails.

Comment: So I suggested to run the install command manually with the debug flag so that you have a clearer output on what’s going wrong

Comment: It could be doing the same, i am not aware about it, but what steps should i follow to get it done.

Comment: can you please list down the steps ? thanks for your prompt respond !

Comment: Okay, do the following: remove the project and generate it new with ng new project-name —skip-install. Then you execute cd project-name, execute npm install -d, share the output

Comment: getting the same error !

attached in question area with your short id @fabi_k

Comment: Thanks you @fabi_k :

steps involved to solve the problem :

**1. clear cache : npm cache clean --force              2.false the strict ssl : npm config set strict-ssl false        3. npm install ;  all these steps performed under project's dir.**